# can I make a directory to git webpage folders?

Tags: html, github-pages

For a github hosted webpage, we can link files with relative links. For example, we can use

```
/image/section1/01.png
```

to link image. However, I want to make a hyperlink to a folder, not a specific file, so that when clicking the link, people will see all files contained in that directory. (see the local example below)

[image]

But if I make a hyper link with

```
/image/section/
```

git webpage says 404 File not found. Is there a way we can link to a folder and it will contains a list of files in it?

Comment: Please add more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you cannot link to folder

if you want to display the the files just add a index.html page and list all the files in the index file